# More than 2 tables JOIN in LINQ, scope issue

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am trying to join 3 table in LINQ.

```
var fromCities = from c in cityRepository.Cities
                             join r in routeRepository.Routes on c.Id equals r.FromCityId
                             join cr in rentDetailRepository.CarRentDetails on cr.CityId equals c.Id
                             select c;
```

I am getting that cr and c do not exist in the second join statement?
Could somebody help?

Comment: you should replace the c.Id whit r.FromCityId like : join r in routeRepository.Routes on r.FromCityId equals c.Id

Comment: Change the order in the last join: `join cr in rentDetailRepository.CarRentDetails on c.Id equals cr.CityId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the order in the last join:

```
...
join cr in rentDetailRepository.CarRentDetails on c.Id equals cr.CityId
```

[join clause (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)

> A join clause performs an equijoin. In other words, you can only base
>   matches on the equality of two keys. Other types of comparisons such
>   as "greater than" or "not equals" are not supported. To make clear
>   that all joins are equijoins, the join clause uses the equals keyword
>   instead of the == operator. The equals keyword can only be used in a
>   join clause and it differs from the == operator in one important way.
>   With equals, the left key consumes the outer source sequence, and the
>   right key consumes the inner source. **The outer source is only in scope
>   on the left side of equals and the inner source sequence is only in
>   scope on the right side.**